# Highly Recommended References for Hyperbolic Planes and Modular Surfaces

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, book-recommendation, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

I would be very grateful if one could suggest highly recommended references for **Hyperbolic Planes** and **Modular Surfaces** that provide a readable self-contained introduction to these concepts.

Comment: It would help if you were to clarify what dimension you are interested in and if by "hyperbolic space" you mean the classical hyperbolic space (of constant curvature -1). There are many references to hyperbolic plane, modular groups and modular spaces/orbifolds in 2d.

Comment: @MoisheKohan please check the following link out  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3998819/asymptotic-winding-of-the-geodesic-flow-on-modular-surfaces-and-continuous-fract

Comment: Then you should modify your question to make it clear that for you a "space" means a "plane" or a "surface."

Comment: @MoisheKohan is it now clear? I still need the references

Comment: This is as unclear as before (without reading a separate post). I suggest you replace the word "hyperbolic spaces" by "hyperbolic plane" and "Modular Spaces" by   "modular surface" or "modular orbifold."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For references, you can use, for instance:

1. The book "Fuchsian groups" by S.Katok. It covers both hyperbolic geometry and the modular group.
2. Or the book *Anderson, James W.*, Hyperbolic geometry, Springer Undergraduate Mathematics Series. London: Springer (ISBN 1-85233-934-9/pbk). xi, 276 p. (2005). [ZBL1077.51008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1077.51008).

(but it only covers hyperbolic geometry and general discrete groups)

3. Or

*Bedford, Tim (ed.); Keane, Michael (ed.); Series, Caroline (ed.)*, Ergodic theory, symbolic dynamics, and hyperbolic spaces. Lectures given at the workshop ”Hyperbolic geometry and ergodic theory”, held at the International Centre for Theoretical Physics in Trieste, Italy, 17-28 April, 1989, Oxford Science Publications. Oxford etc.: Oxford University Press,. xv, 369 p. (1991). [ZBL0743.00040](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0743.00040).

Chapters 1 and 5: Chapter 1 covers basics of hyerbolic geometry and Fuchsian groups while chapter 5 will deal with the modular group, symbolic dynamics and continuous fractions part of the story.

4. Or, freely available Pete Clark's lecture notes on Shimura curves
   [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/expositions2012.html), lectures 0, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Do you think Ratcliffe, John G., Foundations of hyperbolic manifolds, New York, Berlin. Springer-Verlag, 1994 chapter (3) is useful too?

Comment: @Neilhawking It is too long and mostly covers the material you do not need.