# Asymptotic Winding of the Geodesic Flow on Modular Surfaces and Continuous Fractions

Tags: reference-request, proof-explanation, manifolds, book-recommendation, geodesic

**Asymptotic Winding of the Geodesic Flow on Modular Surfaces and Continuous Fractions**. *Y. Guivarc'h* and *Y. Le Jan*. Page **24**.

How to make sure that $K$ and $D$ are normal subgroups of the group $G$ to take the quotients?
[image]
And, in general, I look for a good reference for such concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course these are not normal subgroups, but these are **closed** subgroups; the quotients are understood as smooth manifolds.

Comment: How could this be done?

Comment: @Neilhawking: Jack Lee calls this **Quotient Manifold Theorem**, it was discussed numerous times at MSE, say, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315445/quotient-manifold-theorem-provides-a-fibration).